# How to add strings into one String, Java?

Tags: java

I have 4 strings `String 1 ,String 2 ,String 3 , String 4`. I want to add them to a string called `phones`. However I don't want a simple:
    `String phones = String 1 + "~" + String 2 + "~" + String 3 +"~" + String 4;`

If `String 2 and 3` are empty I would get: `String 1~~~String 4`.

How do I make `phones` only display non empty strings and add `"~"` between each string?  so If `String 2 and 3` are empty, I would get: 
`String 1 ~ String 4` instead.

Comment: The first solutions work just fine thanks! Was my question voted down because it was a duplicate or formatted wrongly??

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry your first question received a negative reaction from some. All the answers got downvoted as well. Ideally, we should be helpful first. Don't let it turn you away from the site. You may find it helpful to read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and Jon Skeet's ["Writing the perfect question"](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and check for empty `String`s with [`String.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(string1);
if (!string2.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append("~").append(string2);
}
if (!string3.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append("~").append(string3);
}
if (!string4.isEmpty()) {
    sb.append("~").append(string4);
}
String phone = sb.toString();
```

*if all the strings but string4 are empty, I will get: ~string4. Is there a way to prevent the ~ without adding a bunch of else if statements?*

You *could* create a utility (or helper) method to `join` your `String`s like

```
static void join(StringBuilder sb, String str) {
    if (!str.isEmpty()) {
        if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sb.append('~');
        }
        sb.append(str);
    }
}
```

and then use that like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string1);
join(sb, string2);
join(sb, string3);
join(sb, string4);
String phone = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I was a minute too late! `StringBuilder` seems like the ideal way too do this.

Comment: @AshwinGupta - A much more concise implementation is possible with Java 8 streams.

Comment: @AndyThomas okay, you just taught me something new today. I've never seen that used before.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch, with this code, if all the strings but `string4` are empty, I will get: `~string4`. Is there a way to prevent the `~` without adding a bunch of `else if ` statements?

Comment: @PrinceA - You get your desired behavior with the simple streams implementation in my answer. Are you using Java 8 or later?

Comment: @AndyThomas I could tell I would, the issue is I am not using Java 8 or later, so I was wondering how I could solve the issue with my limitation in that regard.

Comment: @PrinceA One *possibility*, extract it to a common method; see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need much code at all, if you're using Java 8 or later.

```
String phones = Stream.of( string1, string2, string3, string4 )
               .filter( s -> ! s.isEmpty())  // Filter out empty strings
               .collect( Collectors.joining("~"));
```

If you have null values, you can also filter those.

```
String phones = Stream.of( string1, string2, string3, string4 )
               .filter( Objects::nonNull )  // <-- Filter out nulls
               .filter( s -> ! s.isEmpty())
               .collect( Collectors.joining("~"));
```

**EDIT: Before Java 8**

If you're using an earlier version of Java, one approach is to define the desired operation once, and then call it repeatedly.

```
public static void join( StringBuilder sb, String s ) {
    if ( (null != s) && ! s.isEmpty()) {
        if ( 0 < sb.length()) {
            sb.append( "~" );
        }
        sb.append( s );
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String string1 = "foo", string2 = "", string3 = null, string4 = "bar";

    join( sb, string1 );
    join( sb, string2 );
    join( sb, string3 );
    join( sb, string4 );

    System.out.println( sb.toString() );
}
```

Comment: mind = blown... haven't used java in a while it seems

Comment: Streams can sometimes result in concise code, partly because you're specifying what you want, rather than how to achieve it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java 8, there is now the [java.util.StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html) class.

For example:

```
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner("~");
if (!string1.isEmpty())
    sj.add(string1);
if (!string2.isEmpty())
    sj.add(string2);
if (!string3.isEmpty())
    sj.add(string3);
if (!string4.isEmpty())
    sj.add(string4);

String desiredString = sj.toString();
```